# Creating an ICC Color Profile to simulate vision of color blind people

Tags: color-profile, color-management, color-blindness

I would find it a useful tool to simulate the vision of color blind people e.g. when I prepare a presentation. I can use `xcalib` to assign a specific ICC profile to my monitor.

However, I can't find a Profile that has been created for this task.

on http://daltonize.org I found that "CIE chromaticy corrdinates" have to be specified (see below).

I found the [SampleICC](http://sampleicc.sourceforge.net) programs, which could possibly be used for this task.

Is it possible to convert CIE Chromaticy Coordinates alone to a color profile or is more input needed? Has anyone ever worked with SampleICC and knows how to convert the CIE corrdinates to a suitable input?

> The CIE chromaticity coordiantes (x/y) for each type of color vision
>   deficiency are as follows:
>
> ```
> Protanopia (0.7465, 0.2535)
> Deuteranopia (1.4, -0.4)
> Tritanopia (0.1748, 0.0)
> ```
>
> [(Gamut with CIE chromaticy coordinates for Protanopia)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PS2Hz.jpg)

Below I list help output of several programs of SampleICC I thought could be suitable.

---

**create_display_profile**

> **usage** is: create_display_profile input_file N
>   description copyright output_file  where
>
> **IN.txt** is a file whose
>   contents are:
>
> - measured red XYZ primary (triplet of floats)
> - measured green XYZ primary (triplet of floats)
> - measured blue XYZ primary (triplet of floats)
> - measured medium black XYZ  (triplet of floats)
> - measured medium white XYZ (triplet of floats)
> - N lines being the tone curve for red (floats)
> - N lines being the tone curve for green (floats)
> - N lines being the tone curve for blue (floats)
>
>   **N** is the number of sample points per tone curve,
>
>   **description** is a string which will be used to identify the profile,
>
>   **copyright** is a string identifying the profile content owner, and
>
>   **output_file** is the file which will contain the created monitor profile
>
> **example:** create_display_profile matrix_trc_input.txt 42 "my TRC/Matrix
>   profile" "Copyright (c) 2007 My Little Company - All Rights Reserved"
>   matrix_trc.icc

---

**create_CLUT_profile**

> **Usage:** create_CLUT_profile [OPTION]... DESCRIPTION MEDIA_WHITE SIZE
>   IN_FILE OUT_FILE
>
> **Examples:**
>
> create_CLUT_profile "sample profile" "0.21 0.24 0.52" 11 /tmp/in.txt /tmp/out.icc
>
> create_CLUT_profile -f "0.01 0.005 0.02" "sample profile" "0.21 0.24 0.52" 11 /tmp/in.txt /tmp/out.icc
>
> where   **DESCRIPTION** is a string used to identify the profile, often
>   set to the same as the
>       filename of the profile less any trailing extension,
>
> **MEDIA_WHITE** is a string containing the CIE XYZ coordinates of the
>   media white point
>       with embedded spaces between the X, Y and Z components
>
> **SIZE** is an unsigned integer indicating the number of samples along
>   each edge of the
>       3D lookup table being loaded into the profile
>
> and where the **OPTION** values are as follows:
>
> **-h**  (prints this help text and exits)
>
> **-f** "Xf Yf Zf" (default "0 0 0")  (indicates flare to be subtracted
>   from measurements as a first stage in converting raw   XYZ
>   measurements to the ICC PCS)
>
> **-g** g (default 1.0)  (indicates value of gamma to be used to
>   populate input shaper LUTs -- mutually exclusive   with
>   **--input-shaper-file** option)
>
> **-n** input_shaper_file (default none)  (indicates name of file
>   containing a first line of the maximum encodable value in the    lines
>   comprising the remainder of the file, each of which contains three
>   floating-point   values.  The first line of the file is used to
>   normalize the contents of the rest of   the file.  Mutually exclusive
>   with **--input-shaper-gamma** option
>
> **-L** flag indicating that the profile data should be stored in the
>   LAB PCS (default false)  (unless this flag is specified, profile data
>   will be stored in the XYZ PCS)
>
> **-i**  "Xi Yi Zi" (default same as mediaWhite)  (indicates illuminant
>   used in converting raw XYZ measurements to the ICC PCS -- for
>   projection displays, this usually has a value identical to that of the
>   mandatory   MEDIA_WHITE argument)
>
> **-c** copyright (default "")  (indicates owner, for purposes of legal
>   copyright, of this profile)

---

other programs:

- iccApplyNamedCmm
- iccApplyProfiles
- iccDumpProfile
- iccGamutMapGirdle
- iccGetBPCInfo
- iccRoundTrip
- iccProfLibTest
- iccStripUnknownTags
- iccV4ToMPE
- create_CLUT_profile
- create_CLUT_profile_from_probe
- create_display_profile
- create_pretransform_curve
- create_probe
- extract_probe_data
- flatten_AToB_tag
- generate_device_codes
- reconstruct_measurements
- round_trip_PCS_LAB